# Inconsistency in masking CVV/CVC credit card details during input

Tags: credit-card, payment

I have observed that in some payment portals while making payments via credit/debit card the CVV/CVC number is masked out (hidden), but in different portals this is not the case.

For example: USA & a few of UK based payment portals are not masking this field, while portals of some other countries are not, as far as I know. I tried to find a rule about this, but could not find any.

Is it really necessary to hide this field? Why do payment portals not have a uniform template about managing this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **It is not necessary to hide the field, because there is no rule about how portals have to handle it.**

At least for the United States, you want to take a look at the [PCI Compliance guidelines](https://listings.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v4_0.pdf). Credit card data has to be protected by strong encryption during transmission and storage. But there is no passage about whether a CVC input field has to be masked or not.

That's the reason why there are masked and unmasked variants. **Some payment portals want to avoid mistyped CVCs at all cost and therefore reduce security, others prefer to have better security at the cost of a few mistyped CVCs.** As you get a response whether or not the code is correct almost immediately, I recommend choosing the latter.

Comment: thanks for sharing your views @PasWei

Comment: I'll point out that the only security that masking that field provides is to prevent someone looking over your shoulder while you type.  Which is not _nothing_, but is a very specific, limited usecase you're protecting against.